# Possible to rapidly oscillate brushless motor? Thinking of either running it blind or using a sensored motor - regular BLHeli BEMF modes fail

Tags: motor, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I'm trying to get a brushless motor to rapidly reverse directions thousands of times a second - I don't know how feasible this is. I tried a simple setup with a Raspberry Pi and a BLHeli ESC, tweaked settings, and got some oscillation at the right ones but only about 10 alternations a second. It seemed the setting that made the ESC less reliant on back EMF did the most, so I'm thinking I should either run it blind or look into a sensored motor and ESC.

Comment: kHz oscillation is usually done with a galvanometer. Can you use one of those?

Comment: It's easy. Re-purpose a voice coil actuator (which doesn't have brushes). Most of these have paper or plastic cones attached : if the noise bothers you, remove them *carefully* leaving the voice coil suspension undamaged.